# Cassandra Spark Connector and filtering data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra

I am using Spark 1.3.1 and I have written a small program to filter data on cassandra

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("foo", "bar")
val date = DateTime.now().minusHours(1)
val rdd2 = rdd.filter(r => r.getDate("date").after(date.toDate))
println(rdd2.count())
sc.stop()
```

This program runs for a very long time, printing messages like

```
16/09/01 21:10:31 INFO Executor: Running task 46.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 46)
16/09/01 21:10:31 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 42.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 42) in 20790 ms on localhost (43/1350)
```

If I terminate the program and change my code to

```
val date = DateTime.now().minusHours(1)
val rdd2 = rdd.filter(r => r.getDate("date").after(date.toDate))
```

It still runs for a very long time with messages like

```
6/09/01 21:14:01 INFO Executor: Running task 8.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 8)
16/09/01 21:14:01 INFO TaskSetManager: Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 19395 ms on localhost (5/1350)
```

So it seems like the program will always try to load the entire cassandra table in memory (or try to scan it completely) and only then apply the filter. Which seems extremely inefficient to me.

How can I write this code in a better way so that spark doesn't try to load  the entire cassandra table (or scan it completely) into an RDD and only then apply filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first piece of code

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("foo", "bar")
val date = DateTime.now().minusDays(30)
rdd.filter(r => r.getDate("date").after(date.toDate)).count // Count Filtered RDD
```

So be careful. RDDs are immutable so when you apply a filter you need to use the returned RDD and not the one you applied the function to.

---

```
val rdd = sc.cassandraTable("foo", "bar")
val date = DateTime.now().minusDays(30)
rdd.filter(r => r.getDate("date").after(date.toDate)) // Filters RDD
println(rdd.cassandraCount()) // Ignores filtered rdd and counts everything
```

For more efficency on reading from Cassandra:

If your date column is a clustering key you can use the `.where` function to push down the predicate to Cassandra. Other than that there isn't much you can do to prune data server side.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#filtering-rows---where

Comment: How can I check if the date column is a clustering key? is there some command which I can issue?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but assigning the results of the filter to rdd2 and then doing a count on that. but it is still saying `Finished task 4.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 4) in 112031 ms on localhost (5/1350)`

Comment: Clustering key is a concept which organizes the information on disk in Cassandra. It is a core aspect of your Cassandra Schema. Since you didn't post your code I can't answer why it's taking any amount of time. You should see it running through many tasks. But there are almost no cases where it would be slower than a full table scan without the pushdown.